# Can`t create database in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Havent used SSMS in a while, today i tried to make new database and got this error:

[image]

I tried running as admin, also tried  Security > Logins > myAccount > Server Roles > Checked : sysadmin, dbcreator and still getting that error.

Edit: This is how im trying to add new db:

[image]

Comment: How did you try to create the DB, through a script or the wizard, or...?

Comment: @scsimon Through the wizard, right-click on Database > New Database...

Answer (score 1):

Check Server Properties -- > Database Settings -- > Database Default locations --> Data and log Path.

Reason : Data and Log Path pointed doesn't exist or full rights are not given to this path.

Solution : Specify Correct Data and Log Path or give Full rights to this folder and then try to create database.It should work.

[image]

Below link will also help you :-

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/836873

Comment: @Mlle, its mainly due to insufficient rights try to login with user having sysadmin rights

Comment: Im running it as admin already... i dont understand what could`ve change this, it was working fine for the last year+

Comment: @Mile,can you just verify the registry for SQL Server :-

You need to add 2 strings in the Windows Registry via regedit.exe at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11E.LOCALDB\MSSQLServer:(local SQL Instance Path)

DefaultData --- Data path
DefaultLog   --- Log path

You can refer this link for more info : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23609/sql-server-localdb-instance-error-restoring-backup-masterdbpath-not-available

Answer (score 1):

When creating a database from the wizard, you need to provide a file path. If it is blank by default then it means there is no path specified in Database settings.

In Object Explorer, right-click the server and click `Properties`. In the left panel, choose database settings. In `Database default locations`, view the current default locations for new data files and new log files. To change a default location, enter a new default path name in the Data or Log field, or click the browse button to find and select a path name.

Comment: I have always created databases like that, and have no problems, but i havent used it in 2 months and now im getting this error, as for your advise i cant access that option :( http://i.imgur.com/KLQ6hU9.jpg

Comment: It sounds like someone has changed your permissions. Can you log in as an account with more privileges and see if it works?

Comment: im already admin, this is my home pc, no one uses this but me, as i have said everything was fine before

Comment: You may need to have more priviliges than just admin. Check under "Security" the "Logins" and check the properties of your login. You'll need dbcreator rights under "Server Roles"

Comment: As i have said in my original post, i have tried that also before posting here

Comment: Can you create a new SQL login with sysadmin, dbcreator and also check that the default locations are present? It might even be worth trying to create a new SQL instance and see if you still have problems